# Terminal not prompting properly on tab press

Tags: gnome-terminal, prompt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tab completion doesn't work for commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33440/tab-completion-doesnt-work-for-commands)

The installed packages prompt is working fine, eg, `ged`<kbd>tab</kbd>  completes to `gedit`, but package autocomplete on apt-get is not showing list of matching packages, like, `sudo apt-get install ged`<kbd>tab</kbd> won't try to fit `ged*` packages as it normally should. Similarly, `quickly`<kbd>tab</kbd> pops files and folders in the current directory instead of prompting "commands , create, etc".
Any way of correcting this? And yes, I'm on Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this must work

1. Open Terminal (to start <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)

   > sudo apt-get remove bash-completion && apt-get install bash-completion
2. Either edit the `~/.bash_profile` file to enable it only for a given user or edit `/etc/profile` to add it system-wide(using `gedit`). Add the following code:

```
    if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
    fi
```

> taken from http://www.howtoforge.com/how-to-add-bash-completion-in-debian

Comment: had to put the line in /etc/bash.bashrc, and worked, Thanks :)

Comment: @piyush youre welcome....!