# Bash History is not Working

Tags: bash-history

I recently upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 Server Edition. The first thing I noticed is that my bash history seems to be broken. When I press the up arrow I should be able to view my recent commands, however I simply get a ^[[A character instead. Strangely, bash history works perfectly when I am logged in as root, but it does not work when I am logged in as an user.

Comment: Are you sure you are in a bash shell (not, for example, `dash`)? See [Arrow keys, tab-complete not working](http://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-tab-complete-not-working)

Comment: I think you are right, weird that it is not the default... thanks for your help!

Comment: @Qwintus depends on how you add your user. I think `useradd` uses `sh` as the default, and `adduser` uses `bash` as the default.

Answer (score 1):

It might be that the `~/.bash_history` file is owned by root. If this is the case use `chown` as root to give the ownership to yourself.

```
sudo chown YourUserName ~/.bash_history
```