# Am I using bash or sh?

Tags: bash, remote, sh

I'm connected to a remote shell and many keys aren't working properly such as arrows and the escape key. This answer [Arrow keys, tab-complete not working](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-tab-complete-not-working) suggested I might be in the wrong shell, so I referenced [How to determine the current shell I'm working on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/).  Using the methods described, I get strange results.

```
echo $SHELL 
/bin/bash
```

but

```
echo $0
sh
```

Which shell am I using?

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: This might be system specific, please add details.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### Use proc filesystem to know shell's process name

When in doubt, use `/proc` file system. There's folders per each process, with `comm` file, where that process's command is described. So, knowing shell's PID, we can know what shell it is.

```
$ echo $$
4824
$ cat /proc/4824/comm                                                          
mksh
$ bash
xieerqi@eagle:~$ echo $$
6197
xieerqi@eagle:~$ cat /proc/6197/comm
bash
```

There's also other files that you can reference to extract that same info:

- /proc/$$/stat
- /proc/$$/status
- /proc/$$/cmdline
- /proc/$$/exe  (symlink to the executable itself)

This may not work on [older kernels](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/96788/85039) or systems that don't support `/proc` filesystem ( Mac OS X, for instance ).

#### Variation on the same approach with ps command

`ps` command has `-p` flag which allows you to specify pid. We're still using the same idea of referencing the `$$` variable for that.

```
$ ps -p $$                                                                     
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7728 pts/5    00:00:00 mksh
$ bash
xieerqi@eagle:~$ ps -p $$
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 7776 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
```

---

#### `$0` vs `$SHELL`.

According to [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/environment_variables) ,

> SHELL contains the path to the user's [preferred shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08_03). Note that this is not necessarily the shell that is currently running, although Bash sets this variable on startup.

In other words, this is the users' default interactive shell, the same one that is set in `/etc/passwd`.  This also is the reason why [$SHELL variable doesn't change for subshells](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/45458/85039) . For instance, no matter how many shells i spawn, `$SHELL` variable is unchanged:

```
$ echo $SHELL                                                                  
/bin/mksh
$ bash --posix
bash-4.3$ echo $SHELL
/bin/mksh
bash-4.3$ dash 
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/mksh
```

`$0` argument will display the "self" - the command with which a program or name of the file. So a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $0
```

Will give output like this:

```
$ ./test_script.sh                                                             
./test_script.sh
```

This is also apparent when you do something like this:

```
$ echo 'one two three' | xargs bash -c 'echo $0' 
one
```

For all shells , `-c` option places first command line argument into `$0` variable.

As far as interactive shell goes, $0 usually would be sufficient, but as you can see, it is not reliable way to know what shell you're using. Knowing the process is far more reliable

Comment: echo $$ 
     5373
     cat /proc/5373/comm
     cat: /proc/5373/comm: No such file or directory

Comment: So... you can shorten the command to just `cat /proc/$$/comm`?

Comment: @edwinksl actually . . . yeah . . . It's far simpler that way

Comment: cat /proc/$$/comm
cat: /proc/5373/comm: No such file or directory. Could be failing because this shell could've been launched as a subprocess, which would explain why the the login shell is /bin/bash but I spawned into an sh session.

Comment: @user1800340   Do you have `/proc` directory ? Do `ls /proc` . Does it show output

Comment: @user1800340  nope, I've tested this way with multiple subshells, never failed me

Comment: `cat: /proc/5373: Is a directory` \n `ls /proc/5373     
attr...
auxv...` \n  `cat: /proc/5373/comm: No such file or directory`

Comment: @user1800340  Are you using a virtual machine or this is regular install ? What kernel version this is ? Do  `uname  -r`

Comment: @user1800340 I've made a few edits to my answer, see if that helps you. It is apparent that you're not using Ubuntu , or at least not a recent version of it.

Comment: Thank you. I'm using VMWare on windows 10 to run a Debian distro (4.6.0-kali1-686-pae)  and an Ubuntu distro (2.6.24-16-server). I'm using the Kali machine to connect to the Ubuntu machine. I did hear some things about this Ubuntu distro being out of date. This is partly by design as it's designed to be vulnerable to cyber attacks. I didn't realize the implications would be this bothersome.

Comment: @user1800340  That makes sense now and yes, you have 2.6 kernel there :) You probably can just use either `stat` file or `ps` version of the approach.  If you're studying infosec , that's a good lesson for you - Linux evolves , systems change, and you have to keep open mind and choose attack vectors wisely

Comment: Oh wow, the Arch wiki is not just "not entirely correct", it's flat out wrong! The `$SHELL` variable has absolutely nothing to do with the shell you're currently running. It's just the default shell, as you say. It has absolutely no relation to the shell that's currently running. I've corrected the wiki.

Answer (score 11):

You're using `sh`. Because `$SHELL` refers to the login shell, not the currently one being used.

Your provided [StackOverflow question link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3327013/how-to-determine-the-current-shell-im-working-on) has the correct method to correctly determine the currently running shell.

Comment: That SO question is what OP referenced in his/her question too. :)

Comment: That's correct. However re-reading it I see where I missed the nuances of the provided answer, so it does make more sense now.

Comment: That one is the correct method. I didn't notice the link

Comment: My interpretation is `echo $0` is the canonical way to do this. Is that correct?

Comment: @edwinksl that seems to be the most popular method.

Comment: @edwinksl see my answer , i've added something about `$0`

Answer (score 4):

If the remote OS is Ubuntu (or another GNU/Linux based distribution), a very simple way to figure out what shell you are running is to run this command:

```
ls -l /proc/$$/exe
```

if the remote OS is **not** Ubuntu or at least a similar GNU/Linux distribution, you asked in the wrong site.

If for some reason the remote OS is missing `/proc` (e.g. running a stripped down, incomplete, or antique version of Ubuntu, or maybe a containerized OS instance) the above mentioned command won't work.

Looking to `$0` will give you a clue it is not 100% reliable. Any program can fake its name to something else. In any case, it is very unlikely that you really run `sh` (the real Bourne shell) as it is almost never installed on Linux, you might be running an `sh` clone, likely `dash`.

Answer (score 2):

you seem to be currently using sh. To switch to bash you could just type "bash"

Answer (score 1):

There are already many great answers given, but you can also try issuing `echo $BASH_VERSION`. If this prints out a version number, you are in bash. If it outputs an empty line, you are inside some other shell.