# Where is the login shell defined?

Tags: command-line, bash, sudo

I was reading difference between `sudo -i/-s` [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/376386/618920). After using command `shopt` it is noted that all(`sudo su/sudo -i/sudo -s`) the `$SHELL` are providing same results, but `shopt` command results are different.

So, how is login and non login shell defined?

From where `shopt` get the result?

Why it is not related to `$SHELL`?

**sudo su**

```
givinv@87-109:~$ sudo su
root@87-109:/home/givinv# 
root@87-109:/home/givinv# 
root@87-109:/home/givinv# shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'No login shell'
No login shell
root@87-109:/home/givinv# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
root@87-109:/home/givinv# 
root@87-109:/home/givinv# exit
givinv@87-109:~$
```

**sudo -i**

```
givinv@87-109:~$ sudo -i
root@87-109:~# 
root@87-109:~# shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'No login shell'
Login shell
root@87-109:~# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
root@87-109:~#
```

**sudo -s**

```
root@87-109:~# sudo -s
root@87-109:~# shopt -q login_shell && echo 'Login shell' || echo 'No login shell'
No login shell
root@87-109:~# echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
root@87-109:~#
```

Comment: One problem is that "login shell" has two meanings: 1. It's an instance of a shell started in a specific way that does specific things (like reading `.profile` or equivalents), and 2. It's the shell that's supposed to started at login for a user, as defined in `/etc/passwd` or equivalent. `$SHELL` contains the latter, your `shopt` outputs deal with the former. Typically, when the shell in (2) is started at login, it is started in the specific way needed for (1), hence the conflation of meanings.

Comment: @muru 's explanation is a good one. for example if you SSH into your computer from a remote machine. /usr/sbin/sshd on your system would  fork a shell defined by `$SHELL` (and connect it to a pseudo terminal) which in turn is defined in your /etc/passwd entry. this shell is a login shell and can be tested with `if  [[ -o login ]]; then echo "I am a login shell"; fi`. being a login shell it would perform those tasks appropriate to a new session. e.g. source `~/.zprofile` or similar which would possibly set environment variables  and any custom shell code you might want to run at this time

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**TL;DR**:

- Where is login shell defined? In `/etc/passwd`.
- Are `sudo su`/`sudo su -`/`sudo -i`/`sudo -s` same ? No, they all spawn a shell but differently and in different contexts.
- What does `$SHELL` do? Just tell your default shell, same as in `/etc/passwd`.

**Actual Answer**:

First of all, it's important to mention that `shopt` is bash-specific. For instance, I am `mksh` shell user, and it doesn't have `shopt` , just like `ksh` doesn't.

Next, what exactly `login_shell` is supposed to represent ?  From `man bash`:

> login_shell
>
> The shell sets this option  **if  it  is
>   started  as a login shell**

That's the key point. `sudo -i` , as you already know from previous answer you read, is supposed to simulate initial login. That's why `shopt` reports `login_shell on`  for this option. Think of this as if `sudo -i` forces the shell to go through files that are supposed to appear only during a login process ( which don't get sourced by interactive shells).

In other cases, you already are running an instance of a shell, so it cannot be login shell in the first place, and the purpose of the options is different. `sudo -s` merely reads `$SHELL` (which is meant to represent your default shell as set in `/etc/passwd`) variable and runs it with  root privilege.  This is equivalent to doing `sudo $SHELL` or `sudo mksh` or `sudo bash` ( whichever you happen to use).

Remember I mentioned that I am `mksh` user ? Take a look at this:

```
$ bash --posix
bash-4.3$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 

DIR:/xieerqi|01:53|skolodya@ubuntu:
$ id 
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)

DIR:/xieerqi|01:53|skolodya@ubuntu:
$ echo $-
imsU
```

What you see is that `sudo -s` jumped from `bash` to my `mksh` shell, with the characteristic prompt I've set for it. And of course, since it is not a login action, for `bash` it would report that the shell is spawned as non - login shell instance. In my case, however, you see that `$-` doesn't have a letter `l` there, which would be there if that was a login shell instance.

Finally, the same idea applies to `sudo su` and `sudo su -`. Later one spawns login shell instance (i.e., specific files that are required for login will run) and former one spawns only interactive shells (i.e., login files don't run).

```
bash-4.3$ sudo su
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
root@eagle:/home/xieerqi# shopt login_shell
login_shell     off
root@eagle:/home/xieerqi# exit
bash-4.3$ sudo su -
[sudo] password for xieerqi: 
$ shopt login_shell
login_shell     on
```

So technically, `shopt login_shell` has no relation to `$SHELL` whatsoever. Think of it this way: its purpose is to show *how* bash runs. `$SHELL` is supposed to reflect only what you have assigned in `/etc/passwd`.

As for the difference between login shell and non-login shell, it has been explained by highly-respected Gilles on unix.stackexchange.com in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/46856/85039).

---

**Additional fun**

Here's  something fun you can try. As you may already know, a login shell will run `.profile` (and `.bashrc` since Ubuntu's `.profile` [is configured to do so](https://askubuntu.com/q/432508/85695)) , but non-logins hell will run only `.bashrc` file. So we can test with `echo` which of these commands runs a login shell and which doesn't, and we expect two lines of `echo` for login shell and only one for non-login.

```
$ echo "echo 'hi,i am .profile'"  >> .profile
$ echo "echo 'hi, i am .bashrc'" >> .bashrc
$ sudo -i
hi, i am .bashrc
hi,i am .profile
$ sudo su
hi, i am .bashrc
root@eagle:~# sudo su -
hi, i am .bashrc
hi,i am .profile
$ sudo -s
hi, i am .bashrc
root@eagle:~#
```

Appropriately enough, those with two lines of output will have `login_shell` set to `on`.

Comment: Thank you @Serg and @Zanna. Now about `$SHELL` and `login_shell/non-login_shell` got clarified. But from where `shopt` get details? Is it from `echo $0` ?

Comment: @prado  I would say yes,  since first character of `$0` is used to designate whether or not a shell is a login shell, so if `shopt` would check that variable - sure, it's perfectly acceptable . However, there's probably more than meets the eye. `shopt` probably For this question, I don't have a hard answer, since I'm not familiar with bash's source code that well.

Comment: @prado Bash can be started as a login shell either by having the first character of $0 be `-`, or by using the `-l` option.

Comment: @prado you can read about bash's invocation and options in the man page. for example the SHELL BUILTIN COMMAND's section says `login_shell
        The  shell  sets this option if it is started as a login
        shell (see INVOCATION above).   The  value  may  not  be
        changed.` so the `shopt login_shell` seems to be one way bash lets you find out - programmatically how to know how it was started. the another way would be `[[ -o login ]]`

Answer (score 12):

As @Serg explains [in this answer on how to tell what shell you are running](https://askubuntu.com/a/826276/527764), the `SHELL` variable is just the current user's *default* shell as read from `/etc/passwd`:

```
$ grep zanna /etc/passwd
zanna:x:1000:1000:Zanna,,,:/home/zanna:/bin/bash
```

so if I `echo $SHELL` it will always return `/bin/bash`:

```
$ zsh
% echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
```

Whether or not the shell is a login shell, is a **sh**ell **opt**ion determined at the time the shell is started. The shell program stores this information along with all its other settings and variables. The `shopt` command provides a way to see this information and, if possible for the option in question, to set or unset it (this isn't the case for `login_shell` which, of course, depends on the process used to start the shell)

The `sudo` program's options determine how these different types of root shell will be started:

[image]

Comment: Good explanation. I think you've explained what `shopt` and `login_shell` are supposed to represent far better that in my answer.

Comment: @Serg thanks :) I think your explanation is more thorough :)

Answer (score 3):

`man bash`:

> A login shell is one whose first character of argument zero is a `-`,  or one started with the `--login` option.

`man login`:

> The value for `$HOME`, `$SHELL` [...] are set according to the appropriate fields in the password entry.

In short:

- A shell is a login shell if it was invoked as a login shell.
- The environment variable `$SHELL` is set by `login` or by the invoking program, for example `su`. The shell itself does not set it.
- `shopt` shows the shell options currently in effect.