# Ubuntu - command history not available for newly created user

Tags: 18.04

I have created a new user

```
useradd -d / -G www-data dsweb
sudo passwd dsweb
usermod -aG sudo dsweb
```

I logged in as this user successfully but when I tried pressing up key it shows me something like `^[[A` rather than the commands I typed just few moments ago. If log in as root user everything works fine.

How do I make it work?

Comment: Yes I wanted to create a non-root user but still have sudo access e.g. making changes to apache config as well as changing /var/www files etc. However, I can delete this user account and setup another correct way if you have any suggestions?

Comment: Likely because you didn't set the login shell as `/bin/bash` - see [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell/325812#325812)

Comment: @steeldriver yes perfect that's exactly what I needed. if you can post your comment as answer, I'll accept that the answer or maybe mark this as duplicate question or I can close it?

Comment: @TigerTiger - Step by Step do this as described here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sudo-user-on-ubuntu-quickstart - there is a difference between commands useradd and adduser. This is explained in man pages. When you want to go step by step. You have to remove created user first and reboot before to proceed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `git` developers talk of *plumbing* (low level) and *porcelain* (high level) commands. 
`useradd` is plumbing. You should have used `adduser` (=porcelain) instead.

From [`useradd`'s manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/useradd.8.html):

> **useradd** is a low level utility for adding users. On Debian,
>   administrators should usually use adduser(8) instead.

When using `useradd` you need to specify literally everything, like a home directory and a login shell. `adduser` on the other hand has reasonable defaults for them. The experience you made is either due to having `/` as the home directory (no write permissions there) and/or <s>a wrong</s> no login shell, as @steeldriver noted in a comment. `adduser` handles all this. Thus:

```
adduser dsweb           # create user with default settings (like $HOME, $SHELL)
adduser dsweb www-data  # add him to group www-data
adduser dsweb sudo      # ... and sudo
```

And yes, it's a real mess that we have two commands `adduser` and `useradd`. I myself *always* have to look up which is which.

To remove your previously created `dsweb` user, use `deluser dsweb`. Do ***not*** supply the `--remove-home` switch because you created him with `/` as $HOME and you don't want that removed.

Comment: 1 is a perl script that uses the 2nd as a command.

Comment: @Rinzwind Cool. I wasn't aware. Now it perfectly blends in with the perception that Perl confuses people. Albeit it's not Perl's fault this time.

Comment: PerlDuck not aware of a perl script???  Have a +1 anyway...  **;-)**

Answer (score 0):

Issuing this command from the user account helped me: `chsh -s /bin/bash`.

You need to re-login after issuing the command.

Thanks to this answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/325812).