# Why doesn't auto complete work in my shell?

Tags: command-line, sh, auto-completion, dash-shell

I am not so into Linux and I have the following doubts: a client provided me an Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS virtual machine which I access via SSH. (I am using MobaxTerm as SSH client but it should not be the problem.) The shell used is `sh`.

The problem is that in the shell the autocomplete function is not working as I expected using the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key.

It simply put the classical tab white spaces.

Why? How can I change this configuration?

Comment: Try typing `bash` first (to switch to "bash") and then try to use autocomplete..

Comment: @FedonKadifeli It works, if you put it as response I will accept it

Comment: You can just upvote my comment.

Comment: Related: [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[`sh` is provided by `dash` in Ubuntu.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) Many shells, including `bash` and `zsh`, have sophisticated features for easy interactive use. `dash` is deliberately quite minimal and does not offer such features. In particular, it does not offer tab completion.

Even stripped-down Ubuntu systems typically have `bash` installed because it is considered an essential package--we're supposed to be able to assume it is present even outside the case where another package depends on it. Typically `bash` is the default user shell on Ubuntu--that is, the login shell new users get by default--though this can be reconfigured.

I recommend you use `bash` or another shell that is nice to use interactively. You can see if `bash` is available in that VM by running:

```
bash
```

Assuming your `$PATH` is set reasonably, that will run `bash` if it is available. You can make sure that tab completion works in `bash`--it should, but there's no reason not to check--and then get tab completion in the future through one of two approaches:

- You can just run `bash` when you want tab completion and other `bash` features.
- You can change your user account's login shell to `bash` with the `chsh` command.

Note that there is a separate package called `bash-completion` which is also usually installed. This provides programmable tab completion--that is, tab completion that varies by context and, for example, knows about the flags and other syntax of commands. It's possible to have `bash` installed but not `bash-completion`.

(To find out if any particular package--`bash`, `bash-completion`, or anything else--is installed you can use `apt list package-name`. For more information about a package you can use `apt show package-name` and `apt policy package-name`.)

Answer (score -1):

fish shell  will show you possible commands automatically. Pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd> will show all possible commands. Here is what I get from `sudo ap` + <kbd>TAB</kbd>:

```
shri@shri ~ [1]> sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth
apt                                           (Command-line interface)
aptd               (Package managing daemon proving a D-Bus interface)
aptdcon                            (Command line client for aptdaemon)
aptitude                 (High-level interface to the package manager)
…and 16 more rows
```