# Can't switch between previous command in terminal

Tags: command-line, lxterminal

As in the past I installed Lubuntu but I installed a light one so many things weren't installed.

Today, I noticed that when I use the up arrow key to retype the previous command, instead of showing the previous command as expected it just shows `^[[A`.

What could be the problem?

Comment: What is the output of `echo $SHELL`?

Comment: @yfluK /bin/sh ...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell) Arrow keys don't work as you're expecting in `sh`. Consider switching shell to `bash` or `zsh` (if you know `zsh`).

Answer (score 0):

Try hitting Ctrl+C to exit out of any programs you might be in currently. Then it might work again.

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: Ctrl+C sends interrupt signal to the process executing in foreground. Not always but sometimes it may cause some applications to behave abnormally. For example, if APT is applying updates and the process is interrupted, you may get a broken system.