# How to change user on UbuntuServer

Tags: server

Why when I try to switch user, my console change name from this (%username%@laba2docker) to this ($). I don't have autocomplete in this mode. How can i fix it?

[image]

Comment: Is `admin`'s login shell something other than `bash` (perhaps `/bin/sh`?)

Comment: idk, how can i check it?

Comment: Use `echo $SHELL` from the `admin` account and/or `getent passwd admin` from any account (login shell is in the last field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "fancy" prompt and completion are features of the shell - it looks like your regular user is using `bash` whereas you are getting a simpler shell (most likely `dash`, as the default `/bin/sh`) when switched to the `admin` user.

By default, the utli-linux implementation of the `su` command selects the shell to use according to the following rules (from `man su`):

```
       •   the shell specified with --shell

       •   the shell specified in the environment variable SHELL, if the
           --preserve-environment option is used

       •   the shell listed in the passwd entry of the target user

       •   /bin/sh
```

Since you didn't specify a shell with `--shell` or use the `--preserve-environment` option, it is likely that the `admin` user's login shell is either set to `/bin/sh` or not set at all - you can use the `chsh` utility to set or change it:

- `chsh -s /bin/bash` from the `admin` account
- `sudo chsh -s /bin/bash admin` from another user account with suitable `sudo` privileges

See also [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell)