# history command not working

Tags: command-line

I am a beginner with Ubuntu 22.04.2 Desktop. Some of the commands I used before do not work right now, and history is one of them. Previously, I used MobaXterm to only download and upload files. When I used my account on Ubuntu, this is the same message I got from both of them.

[image]

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu product/release you're using. Have you changed from the default shell?   (*if you use different shells you may find you have different commands available, but have lost some of the BASH default commands*)

Comment: Your screenshot suggests you are using `sh` - history is a feature of more full-featured shells like bash, zsh etc. - see [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell)

Comment: I edited my question for more information. and the version of Ubuntu is 22.04.2 LTS

Comment: `echo "$SHELL"` to see which shell you're using. Read the `man` page for that shell.

Comment: when I used echo "$SHELL" command I got /bin/sh. I googled it and it seems that I should change the sh to bash and there is a command like chsh and when I use that I got permission error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your screenshot, you are using the `sh` shell. On Ubuntu systems, `/bin/sh` is *dash*, the Debian [Almquist shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Almquist_shell), which is a lightweight shell that does not provide shell history features.

To switch to Ubuntu's default interactive shell, bash, you can do any one of

- type `bash` to open a new interactive shell within your sh shell
- type `exec bash` to replace the current sh shell with bash
- type `chsh -s /bin/bash` to set your default login shell to bash - you will be prompted to enter your password to confirm the change.

See also [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell)

Comment: thank you so much. The first one worked. but for chsh -s /bin/bash it says I cannot change it. so it seems I have to use bash command every time.