# Arrow keys not working

Tags: keyboard, gnome-terminal

I am new to Linux and while I tried to use the arrow keys strange characters appeared. Can someone help me? These are the characters while pressing the keys: `^[[D^[[C^[[B^[[A`. Thank you.

Comment: **Welcome to the Ask Ubuntu community.** To help in troubleshooting your issue, please edit your question to include the version of the Ubuntu OS that you're running. Thanks

Comment: So you open a terminal, I assume a prompt (like `username@hostname:~ $`) appears, and the very next thing you do is press the arrow keys and these `^[[A` and friends appear? This is pretty unlikely after a default Ubuntu installation. Or do you do something in between that you forgot to tell us, e.g. start a simple utility that reads its input and doesn't have sophisticated input method? Then it's the expected behavior in that context (and you should only rarely have this experience in real life, much rather when following textbook examples of simple utilities like `grep`, `sort`, `sed` etc.)

Comment: What does `echo "$0"` return?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Arrow keys, Home, End, tab-complete keys not working in shell](https://askubuntu.com/questions/325807/arrow-keys-home-end-tab-complete-keys-not-working-in-shell)