# Tab completion does not work for some commands

Tags: 14.04, bash

I've followed [Tab completion doesn't work for commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33440/tab-completion-doesnt-work-for-commands) and tab completion of filenames is working for this command:

```
ls  /home/login/public/ui.<TAB>
```

But not working for this command

```
drush arr /home/login/public/ui.<TAB>
```

in  `$SHELL` `/bin/bash` is there. Mine is completely new install. I've placed this code in the `.bashrc`:

```
if [ -f /etc/bash_completion ] && ! shopt -oq posix; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
fi
```

`/etc/bash_completion` exists

[Tab completion doesn't work for commands](https://askubuntu.com/questions/33440/tab-completion-doesnt-work-for-commands)

Comment: Both those commands do tab completion correctly for me. Tab completion can be modified by a `.initrc` file in your home directory. Do you have such a file?

Comment: @JohnAnderson no this file is not there.